# Verifying the content of a webpage - avoid code injection

Tags: html, security

Is it possible to verify that the content of a website displayed to the user, to ensure that they are intact and sent by the web site owner.

For example, assume a website is displaying some content about the history of the world. This website is also loading certain javascript files and other resources from third party providers (ex. jquery, bootstrap, or advertising sites). Is it in anyway possible for user (and the website owner) to ensure that what the user sees is what was actually sent by the site owner.

Such concept is easy to do at the website level using SSL/TLS. The user sees the green check mark and can be sure that they are visiting the site they want to see. But is it possible to apply some level of validation to the content of the page using client side or server side code.

Note that I know that this can be done using browser extensions and custom browsers, but Im looking for a way that web designers can perform this task.

Comment: `The user sees the green check mark and can be sure that they are visiting the site they want to see.` it is not true

Answer (score 0):

From a web designer's perspective, and without recommending/forcing an external program or browser extension, this is impossible. Without external verification, the only source of information about your site your user is getting is, well, from your site. You're asking your site to verify itself, which is absurd; if someone can insert malicious code into your site, they would certainly be able to remove/bypass any validation code you have.